# Minimising the shaking or jumpiness of AR video when played over marker image using Vuforia in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am playing video over image target using vuforia plugin in `unity3d`. It is simple green screen video. I am using shader to remove it.

Sometimes when video played over image target it becomes too shaky and jittery and thus reducing the AR experience. How can I avoid or reduce it.

I tried multiple ways to get rid of it but no success. Here is **what I tried**:

- Previously I was embedding the video in a `Plane` then I used `Quad` 
  but no success.
- I tried to change AR camera (`World Center Mode`) to different
  values like `FIRST_TARGET`,`CAMERA` and `SPECIFIC_TARGET` but still same problem.
- Also my `vuforia` target image has 5 rating in vuforia database.

What could be the solution to this problem. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How many starts does your AR target rate at?

Comment: @Draco18s Pardon, couldn't get your question.

Comment: Vuforia rates how good your targets are. How good is the target?

Comment: @Draco18s In question I have mentioned. The images are rated 5 star in vuforia database.

Comment: Missed that, sorry! Not sure what else it could be, then.

Comment: @Draco18s Any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I have no other ideas.,